# Save dxf file in Java

Tags: java, dxf

I am hoping that someone can help me here. I am using the yCad library to read a number of dxf files and output a composite model, to dxf format.

The initial process of reading the file is complete. However, when I save the file it is saved without the model.

Here is an example of the code used to save the dxf file

```
public static boolean SaveDxf(String outputPath, String fileName, Yxxf model)
{
    try
    {
        model.iohandler = new YutilIOHandler();
        model.ioname = new YutilIOHandlerName(fileName);
        model.ioname.dstfile = outputPath + "\\" + fileName + ".dxf";
        YdxfPutHandler handler = new YdxfPutHandler();
        handler.commandPutMainStart(model.iohandler, model);
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("failed to save dxf file: " + ex.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

When the file is viewed from an editor an error is reported stating the model is empty.

The error occurs even when a dxf file is read and then saved with no manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue.

The resolution required a modification to the version of the YCad library that I was using due the following selection.

```
if (ent instanceof YxxfEntLine)
{
    YdxfPutEntLine.put(putbfr, (YxxfEntLine)ent);
}
```

NOTE: This may have been due to an out of date version of the library.

The method was modified to include all required types.

```
else if(ent instanceof YxxfEntPolyline)
{
    YdxfPutPolyline.put(putbfr, (YxxfEntPolyline)ent);
}
```

A number of new classes were added to the solution.

When I get time I will see if I can submit these modification to the source library, if they are required.

Comment: could you give us a short example how to create a dxf file with Ycad?

Just a short snippet with creating a document, adding a line entitiy and save the file? I can't find any examples online and I think this would help alot of people dealing with DXF files in java.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you maybe still have code with saving dxf files? Could you upload it somewhere online?

Comment: Hi there, I will try to provide an example over the weekend. Unfortunately I am too busy with work to do so at the moment.